# WP Media Insert into Text Editor

Tags: wordpress

I have this code that does open Wordpress Media Uploader upon my custom button click and I have everything working from uploading image to selecting an image ...  but how do I send the image/attachment to Text editor

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){

var mediaUploader;

$('#_button').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if( mediaUploader ){
        mediaUploader.open();
        return;
    }

    mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media( {
        title       : 'My Custom Library',
        multiple    : false,
        library     : { type : 'image' },
        button      : { text : 'Select Image' },
        frame      : 'post',
        state       : 'insert',

    } );


    mediaUploader.on('insert', function() {
        var attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

        //WHAT TO DO HERE TO SEND THIS TO TEXT EDITOR??????

    });

    mediaUploader.open();

}); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself from

> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/js/media-editor.js#L852

```
        mediaUploader.on('insert', function() {
        var embed = mediaUploader.state().get( 'selection' ).first().toJSON();
        _.defaults( embed, {
            title:   embed.url,
            linkUrl: '',
            align:   'none',
            link:    'none'
        });

        if ( 'none' === embed.link ) {
            embed.linkUrl = '';
        } else if ( 'file' === embed.link ) {
            embed.linkUrl = embed.url;
        }

        wp.media.editor.insert( wp.media.string.image( embed ) );
    });
```